# How to recover nodes of a deformed grid with python opencv on a noisy image

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

I need to detect intersections on a deformed matrice. Images has a lot of noise.
the quadrangles width can variable in the image.

[image]

What's your recommendations for do this?

First I tried to apply a global image processing but It's not relevant because of the contraste and quadrangles width variation.

Now I'm trying to apply a local image processing. To do this, user click on 3 near intersessions and get U and V vectors.

[image]

Them I run along  each vectors to locate a subwindow to find the next intersection

[image]

Finally I try to detect intersection with Harris but the result is bad

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Harris won't get you anywhere with this. also the first picture is close to undecipherable. a sizable part of it shows no grid at all. you should consider what you can change in the image *acquisition* to make the picture clearer.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz, Thank you for this quick response. Indeed, we are seeking to improve our acquisition at the same time. The problem is that the image will never be clean.